# Redirect to another page in PHP after performing form action on same page

Tags: php, forms, redirect

So I have my page as **downloads.php** and that is where my form is located as well as it's form action.
The **downloads.php**'s contents are as shown below

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<td><button type="submit" name="download" value="<?php echo $g['filename'];?> ">Download</button></td>
</form>
```

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['download']) ){
        $file = $_POST["download"];


        $sql = "UPDATE files SET downloads=1+downloads WHERE filename ='$file'";
        $conn->query($sql);


    //I want to redirect users to portal after updating my database
        header("Location: portal.php");

    }
?>
```

I've used `header` though I'm absolutely puzzled why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Note in the [PHP docs for header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) that header() must be executed before any HTML is output. Try putting all your PHP code at the top of the document and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick way to do it with javascript and that is

```
    <?php
        if( isset($_POST['download']) ){
            $file = $_POST["download"];
            $sql = "UPDATE files SET download=1+download WHERE filename ='$file'";
            $conn->query($sql);
    ?>
    <script>
    var str1 = 'https://www.example.com/portal.php';
    window.location.href = str1;
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```